# Why are the branches of my dracaena marginata shrivelling up and why are all the leaves coming completely off?

Tags: plant-care

I'm having issues with my dracaena marginata. The leaves have begun to turn brown at the tips. But that's not all.
The other issue is the center of the bud like the newest leaf is brown and eventually all the leaves fall off that branch and then it looks as though the while branch begins to shrivel up.
I do not overwater my house plant. I do have a a black light that I turn on every night. It is sitting in an area that gets sunlight.
I've lost 2 branches now.

[image: dracaena marginata]

Comment: Can you add a photo  of the whole plant please, and what do you mean by a 'black light'?

Comment: why are the ends of the leaves clipped off?